# Set the time as 0 which is having value in specific column using python

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a dataset with three inputs X1,X2,X3 including date and time.
Here In X3 column contain with 0 and 5. Here what I want to code is first 5 value contain in X3 column time take as start time and it will be equal to 0 time.

Other time is not changing if 5 value contain in X3 column. Only I want is first time of every day put it as 0 time.

```html
date     time        x3
10/3/2018 6:15:00         0
10/3/2018 6:45:00         5
10/3/2018 7:45:00         0
10/3/2018 9:00:00         0
10/3/2018 9:25:00         0
10/3/2018 9:30:00         0
10/3/2018 11:00:00 0
10/3/2018 11:30:00 0
10/3/2018 13:30:00 0
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5
10/3/2018 15:00:00 0
10/3/2018 15:25:00 0
10/3/2018 16:25:00 0
10/3/2018 18:00:00 0
10/3/2018 19:00:00 0
10/3/2018 19:30:00 0
10/3/2018 20:00:00 0
10/3/2018 22:05:00 0
10/3/2018 22:15:00 5
10/3/2018 23:40:00 0
10/4/2018 6:58:00         5
10/4/2018 13:00:00 0
10/4/2018 16:00:00 0
10/4/2018 17:00:00 0
```

As you see I have X3 column data with values 0 and 5 with date and time.
First taking the value of 5

```
                                                  desired output
10/3/208    6:45:00      5       start time     6:45:00 convert 00:00:00
10/3/2018   13:50:00     5    Not taking 
10/3/2018   22:15:00     5    Not taking 
10/4/2018   6:58:00      5        start time    6:58:00 convert  00:00:00
```

I just want to code like this. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
when we used this code it is giving with time difference of each row. I just don't want the difference of time in each rows. I just want to read start time and it should be converted to the 0 time.

I tried this code, and it gave the time difference of each rows also

```
df['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'],
                            format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
mask = df['x3'].ne(0)
df['Duration'] = df[mask].groupby(['date','x3'])['time_diff'].transform('first')
df['Duration'] = df['time_diff'].sub(df['Duration']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
```

This gave me time duration each of 5 values.

Here what I exactly want:

[image]

Comment: Please share what you have done before.

Comment: @TammoHeeren Yes I shared my code. This is given me the time duration inbetween each 5 values.

Comment: @team Can you post desired output as well?

Comment: @Chris Yes I upload I want to convert my start time into 00:00:00 in every day

Comment: @Chris I hope now you can understanding what I am trying to do. I posted the image of the expected output of time.

Comment: I check your new question a and a bit surprised, why still not data in text? It is impossible copy from pictures. and why is not expected output? there are some new column with timedelta 6? I dont understand it, so cannot answer :(

Comment: @ jezrael  just give me 5 min, I will correct my question.

Comment: @team - It is only friend advice, mainly not forget for expcted output ;)

Comment: @ jezrael  I edited my question. I hope now you will understand my question.

Comment: @jezrael Here is my new question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57781788/unsupported-operand-types-for-float-and-datetime-timedelta-occurred"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filter only first values of `5` per groups add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'],
                            format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
mask = df['x3'].eq(5)
df['Duration'] = (df[mask].drop_duplicates(['date','x3'])
                          .groupby(['date','x3'])['time_diff']
                          .transform('first'))
df['Duration'] = df['time_diff'].sub(df['Duration']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)

print (df)
         date      time  x3           time_diff  Duration
0   10/3/2018   6:15:00   0 2018-03-10 06:15:00       NaN
1   10/3/2018   6:45:00   5 2018-03-10 06:45:00       0.0
2   10/3/2018   7:45:00   0 2018-03-10 07:45:00       NaN
3   10/3/2018   9:00:00   0 2018-03-10 09:00:00       NaN
4   10/3/2018   9:25:00   0 2018-03-10 09:25:00       NaN
5   10/3/2018   9:30:00   0 2018-03-10 09:30:00       NaN
6   10/3/2018  11:00:00   0 2018-03-10 11:00:00       NaN
7   10/3/2018  11:30:00   0 2018-03-10 11:30:00       NaN
8   10/3/2018  13:30:00   0 2018-03-10 13:30:00       NaN
9   10/3/2018  13:50:00   5 2018-03-10 13:50:00       NaN
10  10/3/2018  15:00:00   0 2018-03-10 15:00:00       NaN
11  10/3/2018  15:25:00   0 2018-03-10 15:25:00       NaN
12  10/3/2018  16:25:00   0 2018-03-10 16:25:00       NaN
13  10/3/2018  18:00:00   0 2018-03-10 18:00:00       NaN
14  10/3/2018  19:00:00   0 2018-03-10 19:00:00       NaN
15  10/3/2018  19:30:00   0 2018-03-10 19:30:00       NaN
16  10/3/2018  20:00:00   0 2018-03-10 20:00:00       NaN
17  10/3/2018  22:05:00   0 2018-03-10 22:05:00       NaN
18  10/3/2018  22:15:00   5 2018-03-10 22:15:00       NaN
19  10/3/2018  23:40:00   0 2018-03-10 23:40:00       NaN
20  10/4/2018   6:58:00   5 2018-04-10 06:58:00       0.0
21  10/4/2018  13:00:00   0 2018-04-10 13:00:00       NaN
22  10/4/2018  16:00:00   0 2018-04-10 16:00:00       NaN
23  10/4/2018  17:00:00   0 2018-04-10 17:00:00       NaN
```

Comment: Yes it worked , you saved my day. Thank you very much. I have one question, if you are okay can you help me to solve this also.

Comment: Here now start time take as 0.0 , if I want to add one hour one hour till to 6 hours from this start time, Then how I can add to this method to the start time

Comment: @team - Sure, I have no problem. Btw, I try answer all question if understand it, so it is main reason why ask for exppected output (it is mainly for verify, if understand what need questioner).

Comment: @team - do you think for next 6 rows after `0`? And for each row 1 hour?

Comment: Here in my dataset time is not in every one hour one hour .just ignore  this data. I just normally want to add one one hour till to 6 hours from this start time. start time = 0.0 +datetime.timedelta(hours=1) for 6 hours.

Comment: @team - Is possible see expected output? New column?

Comment: Not in new column, I just want to write it inside the  for loop

Comment: @team - Not understand. What is expcted output from loop? some values, list, new column or another DataFrame, Series?

Comment: @team - Because I can see some formula, but not understand it, becuse no idea how implement this formula without expcted output, sorry :(

Comment: I am expecting some values, by using summation equation. For that I need this time loop. I will ask new question, with that formula, I hope you will help me to solve that new question. Because I am stuck with this. Thank you.

Comment: @team - Maybe the best create new question, but not sure if I know answer. Because my problem is not understand this formulas :(

Comment: @yes I will ask a new question, you may probably understand my code with that equation. Give me some time to ask the question in best way.