# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'datetime.timedelta'", 'occurred at index 5')

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a dataset with one input with date and time .
First I wrote the code to find the first time of 5 value in X3 column and I turn that time into 0.
Then I tried to add timedelta(hours=1) into that which is having range 6.
Then it gave me this error `"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'datetime.timedelta'"`

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

my code:

```
data =pd.read_csv('data6.csv')

data['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
               format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
mask = data['X3'].eq(5)
data['duration'] = data[mask].drop_duplicates(['date','X3']).groupby(['date','X3'])['time_diff'].transform('first')
data['duration'] = data['time_diff'].sub(data['duration']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
```

```
date    time    x3            Time(expected)
10/3/2018   6:15:00     0        NaN
10/3/2018   6:45:00     5        0.0
10/3/2018   7:45:00     0        NaN
10/3/2018   9:00:00     0        NaN
10/3/2018   9:25:00     7        NaN
10/3/2018   9:30:00     0        NaN
10/3/2018   11:00:00    0        NaN
10/3/2018   11:30:00    0        NaN
10/3/2018   13:30:00    0        NaN
10/3/2018   13:50:00    5        NaN
10/3/2018   15:00:00    0        NaN
10/3/2018   15:25:00    0        NaN
10/3/2018   16:25:00    0        NaN
10/3/2018   18:00:00    7        NaN
10/3/2018   19:00:00    0        NaN
10/3/2018   19:30:00    0        NaN
10/3/2018   20:00:00    0        NaN
10/3/2018   22:05:00    0        NaN
10/3/2018   22:15:00    5        NaN
10/3/2018   23:40:00    0        NaN
10/4/2018   6:58:00     5        0.0
10/4/2018   13:00:00    0        NaN
10/4/2018   16:00:00    7        NaN
10/4/2018   17:00:00    7        NaN
```

So here I have a summation equation to apply for X3 column value.

[image]

Then according to this summation equation I want to take the value of X3 in every hour.

That's why first I found the start time of mention value of 5 in every day and then convert that time into 0:00:00.

Then from that start time adding one hour one hour till to 6 hour I need to take the value for A.

For A equation is :

```
A =  X3(5) - M
```

So first I took the first time separately, 0 time only.
For that I used the code :

```
time= data['duration'].eq(0)
```

Then I wrote this equation method inside the class

```
time=0
M=0
for _ in range(len(data['X3'])):
  if X3.all()==5:
    if time ==data['duration'].eq(5).all():
        M=X3
        for i in (time + timedelta(hours=1*it) for it in range(6)):
            M = 5 - 0.0015 * np.sum(i*X3) 
print(M)
```

Then got the values only 0 .

Then this error came .

From these code what I am expecting output is:

```html
     
    time                         expected output  
 0 (start time of x3 value of 5)         5  
 1 hr                     5-0.3(according to the summation equation) = 4.7  
 2hr                        5-0.6=4.4  
 3hr                        5-0.9=4.1  
 4hr                        5-1.2=3.8  
 5hr                        5-1.5=3.5  
 6hr                        5-1.8=3.2
```

Comment: For the community to be able to answer your question, please add the data you were using (or, more correctly, a minimal example that reproduces the error), in a format we can copy and paste it to check what would work (i.e. not a screenshot). To learn how to do so with for a pandas question, please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @Itamar Mushkin Yes I edited my question. I hope now you will understand  y question.

Comment: Super, question is better. But I want ask about 6 hours. It means next 6 rows after `X3== 5` ? values in `time` are used in your solution in `time + timedelta(hours=1*it)` what is reason? There is some filtering by values of column `time` ?

Comment: Also if check your expcted output then is subtract [0,0.3,0.6,1.2,..] from 5? So `time` column values are not used for count?

Comment: @jezrael Actually what I want to say that in X3 column  has 5 value.  First 5 value is starting at 6:45:00 a.m. So my first time is this and it is mentioned as 00:00:00. Assume we plot the graph. x axis is time. Then 0 time y value is 5. From that value , and from starting time one hour one hour value will be reduce according to  the summation equation value in range for 6 hours.  that's why I want to take the start time of X3 ==5 value. These  expected output will be save with time in  another data csv.

Comment: @jezrael Then how I can take the value for each hours without time?

Comment: @jezrael from csv file I want to take the only time period which is include 5. Then applying summation equation and the value will not be affiliated to this csv file. it will be display in another csv file.

Comment: @jezrael I changed my code. I tried new code, then it gave me only 0 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `time= data['duration'].eq(0)` this part is making the `time` variable of bool type.
Try to convert it to `0 or 1` then add it in for loop.

If `time` is scalar (single) value :

```
if (time==True):
    time=1
else:
    time=0
```

if `time` is vector (array) :

```
time_array = [0 if tm==False else 1 for tm in data['duration'].eq(0)]
```

Also, there is one more mistake in your for loop. You can't add `1` like this to data time.
Try this :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
current_time = datetime.now()
nine_hours_from_now = current_time  + timedelta(hours=9)
```

In this code you can replace `timedelta(hours=9)` by your time `timedelta(hours = time)`.

**Note** : your `time` will be a binary array. you have to reaverse is to pick the values and add.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. No this code will give another error like "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: There is one more issue in your last for loop, I have edited my answer please take a look, hope this will help.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question. Sorry your code is not corrected. Thank you for trying and replying me.